# ReactJS & Electron - Execute Function passed by variable: string

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

Given a variable foo='someFunc', I'd like to be able to then call someFunc().

There is a relevant write-up about pure javascript doing exactly this [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/call-javascript-function-string-without-using-eval/).

I can't seem to get there with React.

I'm currently doing `returnFuncFromString()`:

```
export default (func: string) => {
  switch (func) {
    case 'UpAvlToast': return toasts.UpAvlToast();
    case 'UpRcvdToast': return toasts.UpRcvdToast();
    default:
      return null;
  }
};
```

but after a handful of maps, this will become difficult to manage. It is being used to pass constants of message and icon variables to a **toastr** component. It wouldn't be surprising to have hundreds of preconfigured pairs so I'm hoping for something more dynamic.

There have been similar questions in java, and pure javascript but as there are `window` lookup issues involved in the **electron** bifurcation of the main and render threads they aren't terribly helpful.

Comment: since you are calling `toasts.<func>` why not `toasts[func]()`?

Comment: I guess what you want is `func => toasts[func] ? toasts[func]() : null` *" but as there are window lookup issues involved"* `window` is  an object. You can apply the same solutions to any other object.

Comment: Thanks everyone - the bracket approach works as you've advised. Going to accept the one posted as an answer - but againt ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of the functions are methods of the object `toasts`, then you should be able to use bracket notation as follows:

```
export default (func) => toasts[func] ? toasts[func]():null;
```

The arrow function will the return the result of the ternary operator  (he value that `toasts[func]` evaluates to of it exists or `null`)

If there is a method on `toasts` that matches the variable `func`, this is what will be returned.